# IIS default website conditional redirect upon domain name

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, iis-8

I have many websites hosted on the same IIS. When I stop one of them, and trying accessing it, it renders the default website of IIS. i.e `iisstart.htm`.

What I need to have is, for example, when `example1.com` has been stopped and trying to access its home page or better any URL on it i.e `example1.com/some/path` it redirects to an other defined page on the root of the default website, such as, `example1.html`. Also, I need the solution to be applied as many as websites that I have, i.e `example2.com`, `example3.com` and so on.

I have tried the following `web.config` settings, but it does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>

            <rules>
                <rule name="conditional products redirect" enabled="true"> 
  <match url="^example1(.*)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
  <conditions> 
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/example1.html" /> 
  </conditions> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="/example1.html" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" /> 
</rule> 
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The HTTP host name line is completely wrong.

Comment: @LexLi How could I fix it? I don't know enough about IIS conf.

Comment: http://learn.IIS.net has some materials while you can learn from existing examples all over the Internet.